# KML Layer not showing on Google Maps using Javascript API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a KML file which is not loading on Google maps. Here is the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rh0az9rr/

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
    zoom: 4, 
    center: {lat: 39.8282, lng: -98.5795} }); 
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({ 
    url: 'http://www.agstechnologies.com/counties.kml', 
    map: map 
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KmlStatus returned by the API is `INVALID_DOCUMENT`.

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rh0az9rr/1/)

[Your KML file is 14 MB](http://www.agstechnologies.com/counties.kml).  [The allowed limits are](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions):

> (Note: These limits are subject to change at any time.)
>
> Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)  **3MB**
>
> Maximum uncompressed KML file size **10MB**
>
> Maximum number of network Links 10
>
> Maximum number of total document-wide features 1,000

Your KML is also invalid (there is a blank line at the top of the XML before the `<xml>` tag).

One option to display KML that is bigger than these limits is to use a third party parser (like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/archive/p/geoxml-v3/)): [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/counties_SO_20161011.kml)

However, there could be performance issues (which is why google has those limits).  The best option is to:

1. use a KMZ file (compressed KML)
2. reduce the complexity of your KML

Or use a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer) to display the data from FusionTables.